# NSDate setHour is giving wrong hour

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I am using this to set the time of uilocalnotifications. I want them to trigger at a certain time for whatever timezone the user lives.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] ;
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components: NSUIntegerMax fromDate: date];
[components setHour: 7];
[components setMinute: 59];
[components setSecond: 17];

NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateFromComponents: components];
```

The minutes and seconds update correctly but the hour is always off.
date is the original date passed and fire date is what I get when I attempt to set the time. The minutes and seconds are correct but the hour is off. Any clues?

```
date 2016-10-29 02:54:18 +0000
firedate 2016-10-28 14:59:17 +0000
```

Comment: This answered my question. I forgot that NSLog will always be GMT. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11133736/528828

Comment: This answered my question. I forgot that NSLog will always be GMT. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11133736/528828